# Debian Squeeze KVM - No Matter How I Setup Bridge, No Connectivity on Guest

Tags: networking, debian, kvm-virtualization, debian-squeeze, libvirt

I'm attempting to setup libvirt KVM guests on my server, and I've been messing around for two days now trying to get the guest networking working. So far, I haven't gotten anywhere.

My network is DHCP, but I have my server setup to pull a static IP.

I'm doing this all with the future intent of moving the machine to a datacenter, where things become even more complicated, in terms of multiple IP's and vlan's, so if you can point me in the direction of a guide or doc somewhere that will help me learn what to do there as well, it'd be really appreciated.

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces:
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.200
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp no
```

And here's the line I'm trying to use to setup a VM. All works but the networking. Note I'm using a block device for storage, so if that looks weird, that's why.

```
virt-install --name irssi --ram 512 --vcpus=1 --vnc --disk /dev/mapper/irssi \
    --network bridge=br0,model=virtio --virt-type kvm \ 
    --location=http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer\-amd64
```

Comment: This really should be simple, should it not? br0 is getting an IP, it's just that my VM's aren't connecting. They pull an IPv6 IP, which I actually have disabled, but otherwise can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to the kernel parameters from the CD's bootloader and it worked:

```
doload=virtio_pci,virtio_blk
```